# results.length is not give the correct output for MySQL query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, string-length

Why the length of result of MySQL query is not correct? The query is just count the number of `message` column in database and print the length.

the code:

```
connection.query("SELECT COUNT(message) as total FROM `counter`", (err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(results);
    console.log("the length of result:", results.length);
```

the output:

```
[ RowDataPacket { total: 4 } ]
the length of result: 1
```

The correct length is `4` not `1`.

How to correct that, please?

Comment: There is only one value returned: a `count` of 4. How many `count` values do you expect? We are ony counting once not 4 times. The actual result you want is probably something along the lines of `console.log(results.total)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`results` contains the rows returned as an array. Since you're using `SELECT COUNT(message)`, you're querying for the count of messages, which returns one row. This one row contains the result, which is an object of shape `{ total: 4 }` - where the `total` comes from the `as total` part of your SQL query.

To get the actual result, check that `results.length > 0` and then you can access `results[0].total`:

```
if (results.length > 0) {
  console.log('Total:', results[0].total)
} else {
  throw new Error('No results returned from query!')
}
```